# SetSupportActionBar on Fragment does not set SupportActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Following sample [Android-Support/Fragments](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/8dd5707ebd8d2158cf0e5197060295bad4ba7f36/TestProjects/Android-Support/Fragments) for MvvmCross and trying to refactor my own app to move AppBar and Toolbar resource definition to fragments.  I am having having problems with the call to SetSupportActionbar on the fragment while the call used to work fine on the Activity.  Here is the refactored code:

activity_main.axml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Actual content of the screen -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content.PM;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat;
using Mobile.Core.ViewModels;

namespace Mobile.Droid.Activities
{
    [Activity(
        Label = "@string/applicationName",
        Icon = "@drawable/ic_icon", 
        Theme = "@style/AppTheme.Default",
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
        Name = "droid.mobile.activities.MainActivity")]
    public class MainActivity : MvxAppCompatActivity<MainViewModel>
    {
        ...    
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            ViewModel.ShowLists();
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

fragment_lists.axml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.ToolBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/listsRefresher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:MvxBind="Refreshing IsLoading; RefreshCommand ReloadCommand">

        <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_list"
            app:MvxBind="ItemsSource Lists; ItemClick ShowListItemsCommand" />

    </MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main_content_frame"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ListsFragment.cs

```cs
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4;
using MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext;
using Android.Runtime;
using List.Mobile.Droid.Common;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Widget;
using List.Mobile.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Views.Attributes;

namespace List.Mobile.Droid.Views
{
    [MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.main_content_frame, true)]
    [Register("list.mobile.droid.views.ListsFragment")]
    public class ListsFragment : BaseFragment<ListsViewModel>, ActionMode.ICallback
    {
        ...    
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            ...
        }
   }
}
```

BaseFragment.cs

```cs
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4;
using List.Mobile.Droid.Common;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

namespace List.Mobile.Droid.Views
{
    public abstract class BaseFragment<T> : MvxFragment<T> where T : MvxViewModel
    {    
        protected AppBarLayout AppBar { get; set; }
        protected FloatingActionButton FAB { get; set; }
        protected Toolbar Toolbar { get; set; }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            AppBar = Activity.FindViewById<AppBarLayout>(Resource.Id.main_app_bar);
            FAB = Activity.FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
            Toolbar = Activity.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.main_tool_bar);
            AppCompatActivity parentActivity = ((AppCompatActivity)Activity);
            parentActivity.SetSupportActionBar(Toolbar);
            parentActivity.SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            parentActivity.SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(false);

           return view;
       }
     }
}
```

Problem is with line:

```
parentActivity.SetSupportActionBar(Toolbar);
```

As it does not seem to set the action bar and subsequent calls to **parentActivity.SupportActionBar** fail with NullReferenceException.  Any ideas?  Do please not that this worked when the Appbar and Toolbar were defined on the Activity rather than the Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot see the answer, take a break, have a coffee and it will come to you. Since the AppBar and the Toolbar is defined in the fragment XML, I cannot call **Activity.FindViewById()** to inflate it.  The same applies in the above code to AppBar and FAB.  Once I refactored the code closer to the above mentioned example I was following (sub-class Fragment provides ResourceId of the fragment layout and base class inflates it), I was able to change the calls:

```cs
AppBar = Activity.FindViewById<AppBarLayout>(Resource.Id.main_app_bar);
Fab = Activity.FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
Toolbar = Activity.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.main_tool_bar);
```

to:

```
AppBar = FragmentView.FindViewById<AppBarLayout>(Resource.Id.main_app_bar);
Fab = FragmentView.FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
Toolbar = FragmentView.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.main_tool_bar);
```

where:

```
FragmentView = this.BindingInflate(FragmentResourceId, null);
```

everything started to work just fine.